# I want to loop through files that have been made corresponding to a prompt

Tags: matlab, file, for-loop, text-files

I have several text files: (participant1, participant2, participant3,....participant5)

I have made these files using a loop. My loop for that is something like this:

%The subinfo_vect is a prompt that allows users to input what number they are, so every time there is a new file. 
    %This appends the results x y z h within file

```
for i = 1
      empty_mat = zeros(0);
      filename=['participant', subinfo_vect, '.txt']; 
       dlmwrite(filename, [x,y,z,h], '-append'); 
    end
```

This code creates files corresponding to our prompt (subinfo_vect). Now I was wondering how to loop through these files (6 in total) so that we can catch the result and find the mean of those. To clarify the results, each file (txt) looks like this (below) and I need to find the mean of column 2 and 3:

```
n =
    1.0000    1.0000    1.2986    1.3973
    1.0000         0    0.4159    0.5138
    1.0000    1.0000    0.3955    0.4924
    1.0000         0    0.3574    0.4539
    1.0000    1.0000    0.3489    0.4458
    1.0000    1.0000    0.4403    0.5372
```

How do I loop through 6 files that look like the above so that I can get the mean of all 6 in sequence? Any ideas?

What I have so far is a manual input of loading all the files. I am manually reading those files by adding:

`dlmread('participant1.txt')` <-- This however is manual, I want the computer to do it automatically without me giving the command, so something where I can just input a looping folder and it will read all the files one by one? Using a for loop?
Can you please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have saved your .txt files in a folder called `myFolder`, then:

```
fileList=dir([myFolder '/*.txt']);
fileList={fileList.name}; %just extracting names for convenience.
for i=1:length(fileList)
    contents=dlmread([myFolder '/' fileList{i}]); %do something
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable `looping_dir` as a string containing the directory name where your files are saved in, and then loop over it. You can try something like this:

```
files = dir([looping_dir '*.txt']); % get files ending .txt in given directory
for f = 1:numel(files)
    data = dlmread([looping_dir files(f).name]);
    % do calculations...
end
```